# How libc modifies the CS register in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to use the LDT (Local Descriptor Table) in Linux. I set up a LDT entry, LDT[0] for the new code segment. Then I tried to update the %CS with `ljmp`. I find the %CS updated after the `ljmp` instruction, but then it changed back to the original %CS value just after a `printf` function. So I'm wondering the `libc` modifies the %CS register, but I have no idea how this happens and how can I use the LDT specified by myself?

Here is the code:

```
// allocate and setup an LDT entry
struct user_desc *def_seg = (struct user_desc *)malloc(sizeof(struct user_desc));
def_seg->entry_number = 0x0;
def_seg->base_addr = 0x0;
def_seg->limit = 0xfffff;
... ...
ret = modify_ldt(1, (void *)def_seg, sizeof(struct user_desc));

asm("movl %%cs, %0":"=r"(val)::);  // get and print the %cs value
printf("val(cs) 0x%x\n", val);     // val(cs) 0x73

// load the LDT into %cs, since x86 does not 
// allow us to explicitly modify the %cs register
asm("ljmp $0x7, $reload_cs\n\t"
    "reload_cs:\n\t");

asm("movl %%cs, %0":"=r"(val)::);  // get and print the %cs value
printf("val(cs) 0x%x\n", val);     // val(cs) 0x7
asm("movl %%cs, %0":"=r"(val)::);  // after a printf. get and print the %cs value again.
printf("val(cs) 0x%x\n", val);     // val(cs) 0x73
```

I used the LDT allocated by myself just want to test some x86 segmentation features for a small research project.

I'm working on an i386 machine with Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel version 4.1.9). It is just a small research project trying to exploit some segmentation feature.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the use case? On which processor and OS architecture?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I'm working on an i386 machine with Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel version 4.1.9). It is just a small research project trying to exploit some segmentation feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux/x86-64 don't really use the segment registers, expect for thread local storage (and they are probably managed by the kernel, not only the libc). And it is mostly the kernel which sets them. Read the [Linux x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) for details (or the [Linux ia32 ABI](http://www.caldera.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) for 32 bits x86); see other references [here](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-IA32/LSB-Core-IA32/normativerefs.html) for 32 bits and [here](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-AMD64/LSB-Core-AMD64.html) for 64 bits).

Read more about [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) & [set_thread_area(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/set_thread_area.2.html) & [modify_ldt(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/modify_ldt.2.html)

I guess that thread creation might set some segment registers (see [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)...). Study the source code of the [NPTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) part of your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (which is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)), e.g. [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/)

You probably **should not** and cannot (without using [modify_ldt(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/modify_ldt.2.html))  **change segment registers** in Linux 32 bits x86 user code. IMHO they have been only useful in the previous century, for 16 bits MSDOS... Read the wikipage on [x86 memory segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation)

IMHO current processors do not handle efficiently segment register changes. **Don't use segment registers** in your code (outside of their predefined usage). Segment registers are for the previous century (or for the BIOS in 16 bits mode).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm gonna read the ABI and those links. It looks like the C library sets the segmentation register (especially the %cs) on entering the libc and restores those seg registers back to default USER_SEG when leaving the libc. BTW, I'm using i386 HW.

Comment: I don't think that the `libc` is setting CS and other segment registers. It is the kernel which sets them.

Comment: Yes. I think you are probably right. Maybe the kernel sets them. :) The protected mode segment registers are still being used in x86. For example, the the Linux kernel stores per-cpu data in GS specified segment. Some other interesting features in code segment might be still useful.